# How to find the file which declares a namespace variable?

Tags: c++, namespaces, grep

I've got a program (LAMMPS, as it happens) spanning many .cpp/.h files, all of which share a namespace. There are many variables referenced in source files, but which are initialised in some other file.

Is there a way to find which file the variable is initialised in?

Perhaps this is better placed in superuser, as I reckon some clever find/grep work could do this, but I'm not even sure what I'd be looking for (I don't know what type the variables are, for example).

Comment: This is probably the major reason why so many people hate global variables.

Comment: Hacky solution: just use `grep -r "variable_name" *` to get a list of all references in all files in the current dir and its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with 'ctags'.  It will create a cross reference listing of all the symbols in your code.  Of course find & grep will work too :)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Chosen as it's fairly standard and integrates with Emacs

Answer (score 1):

There are some good cross-referencing tools out there. Look for LXR, Cxref or OpenGrok.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my VIM favourites:

- position the cursor on the identifier
- hit

  - <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, or <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
  - <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, or <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
  - <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
  - <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- alternatively do the include search:

  ```
  :isearch /regex/
  ```

Be sure to set `path` to include your include paths:

```
:se path+=/usr/local/mylibrary/include
```